# identityserver using aspnetidentity id_token on server reboot

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have identityserver4 with aspnetidentity, it is working but on server restarts the application redirects user to signing again.

```
 services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
       {
           options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
           options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
           options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
           //options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
           options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
       }).AddSigningCredential(cert)
            //.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            //.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            //.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            //.AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
            .AddConfigurationStore(builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddOperationalStore(builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                     options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()                
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

with access token I don't have any issue, because it is with the client browser in cookie format. no matter if server restarts still the resource allow.

but id_token which is the same case, however when the request goes to Idmsrv endpoints connect/authorize it gets the user to login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persists the keys to disk rather in memory so it will have a key when the cookie come back to server to decrypt using the key.

//REFERENCE [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-core-authentication-in-a-load-balanced-environment-with-haproxy-and-redis)

//REFERENCE persists keys http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-core-authentication-in-a-load-balanced-environment-with-haproxy-and-redis

```
services.AddDataProtection() //Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis package
                        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("F:\\Jana\\Certs\\Keys\\"));
```